# How to get max salary from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables from which i want to get **maximum salary** & the **employee name**. Here is the table 1st is **emp_info** & 2nd is **emp_salary**.
[1st Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB6IV.png)
[2nd Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SKcS.png)

The output i need is...

e_name   |   e_salary

abc    |    35000

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) are the keywords you are looking for. Good reading

Comment: just use `MAX()` or you can do `order by e_salary  desc limit 1` and need to `join` other table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below using subquery

```
select e_name,e_salary from  emp_info a
inner join emp_salary b on a.emp_id=b.emp_id
where e_salary in (select max(e_salary) from emp_salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
`SELECT e_name,MAX(e_salary) FROM table1,table2 WHERE e_id.table1 = e_id table2 GROUP BY(e_salary)`
```

[This article](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/Max-with-group-by.php) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

you can follow previous answer or

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `emp_salary` es
INNER JOIN emp_info e ON e.e_id = es.e_id 
ORDER BY es.`yearly_salary` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```